# Add button from button.html to index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, addition

I have this code in the file button.html

```
 <button class="add_button">Add button</button>
```

that clicking invokes this function that is in the file button.js and creates a button

```
$(function(){
    var max_button      = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".light_ponte"); //button wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_button"); //Add button on ID

    var i = 1;
    var x = 1; //initlal button count

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();

        if(x < max_button){ //max button create
            x++; //button increment
            i++;

            $(wrapper).append(' `<div class="checkbut"> <li> <input class="box" type="text" name="mytext" id="mytext" maxlength="15"> <label class="checkboxControl"> <input type="checkbox" value="i" /> <div>OI</div><b></b> <span class="indicator"></span> </label> <a href="#" class="remove_button">X</a> </li> </div>`'); //add button

        }
    });
});
```

This button, however it must create index.html. That is, by clicking on the add button that is in the file button.html, is created a button in the file index.html.

is there a way to do it?

Comment: what are you trying to say?

Comment: so where is the index.html? don't see any relation with your code?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to do this: `var add_button = $(".add_button");`  You have already reference jQuery once with the add_button variable, you don't need to pass that to the $ function again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you'd like to do, please have a look at the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fX8QpADjqWhCRXy524Vs?p=preview).

With the jQuery `load` method you can load a html file like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('body' ).load( "button_template.html" , function() {
    // called after button_template is loaded and added to the body
    button_handler();
  });
});
```

You then need to attach in the onload callback the click handler for the button to be able to click the newly loaded button. That's what `button_handler()` does.

Answer (score 0):

In file index.html there is a main screen, with several div. On the screen there is the setup button. When I click on setup, i move on file button.html , where i have "add_button" . When i click on "add_button" , must be generated a button in a specific div, which is located in index.html.